# Returning JSON from django-rest-framework for use in table visualization front end

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, django

I'm trying to get my django-rest-framework to render a table using google chart data drawing library but somehow I keep getting an error "You called the draw() method with a String rather than a DataTable or DataView". I have tried to change the ajax call to $.ajax.getJSON but that didn't help either, that just returned a blank page.

When I go to localhost:8000/api/v1/total/?format=json, I get the proper json data, but I can't seem to get it to appear in my index.html file below through a call with ajax. I could really use some help. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

    function drawTable() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "/api/v1/total/?format=json",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;


      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(jsonData, {showRowNumber: true});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from .models import Weekly, Monthly, Yearly
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import WeeklySerializer, MonthlySerializer, YearlySerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def weekly_collection(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        week_data = Weekly.objects.all()
        serializer = WeeklySerializer(week_data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def monthly_collection(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        month_data = Monthly.objects.all()
        serializer = MonthlySerializer(month_data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def yearly_collection(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        year_data = Yearly.objects.all()
        serializer = YearlySerializer(year_data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def total_collection(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        year_data = Yearly.objects.all()
        month_data = Monthly.objects.all()
        week_data = Weekly.objects.all()
        serializer_month = MonthlySerializer(month_data, many=True)
        serializer_week = WeeklySerializer(week_data, many=True)
        serializer = YearlySerializer(year_data, many=True)
        return Response([serializer_week.data, serializer_month.data, serializer.data])

def index(request):
    return render(request, "sales/index.html")
```

Comment: `url: "/api/v1/total/?format=json",` missing `?` ?

Comment: good catch, but still the same problem, maybe the call isn't getting it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The draw method on the google visualization table expects a google visualization DataTable. There is a GVIZ python library for creating and sending such an object from the Django view on the response.